# ZF2 Bulk copy ViewModel variables in phtml

Tags: php, zend-framework2

While accessing variables in local function within view phtml file I get this popular error

```
Using $this when not in object context
```

I want to know is there any way by which I can bulk copy all the variables and objects in Variables container data structure of ViewModel defined in Controller, as local variables and objects to view so I can use them in local functions?

In otherwords, like someCreateVariablesFromViewModelArray method to call in phtml. Because I have lot of data in ViewModel Variables container array in Zend Framework 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have something like this:

```php
//view + some html
<?php
    function something() {
        //do sth
    };
?>
<p>some text</p>

<?php something() ?>
```

1. I recommend writing a [view-helper](https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/07/20/zend-framework-2-create-your-custom-view-helper/). There you have access to the view or can inject components you need.
2. You can inject $this into your function:

```php
//view + some html
<?php
    function something($view) {
        //do sth
    };
?>
<p>some text</p>

<?php something($this) ?>
```

3. Don't know how it is called but I am sure this is also a (not so good) solution:

```php
<?php
    $something = function() use ($this) {
        //do sth
    };
?>
```

Comment: not the one i am looking but it saved my guts. thanks.